# How to update querystring without using response.redirect which affects on performace of application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Given code is working properly but while checking page url on redirect checker,it gives error as too many redirections which may affect on performace of app.

if (Request.QueryString[null] != null)
        {
            string LastIndexOFUrl = Request.RawUrl.Substring(Request.RawUrl.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

```
        if (lang == "eng")
        {
            //Session["ServiceName"] = Request.QueryString[null].ToString();

            //
            dt2 = FEManager.GetOurServiceByID(CommonFunction.GetLangType(), LastIndexOFUrl);

            if (dt2.Rows.Count > 0)
            {                   
                string Name_En = dt2.Rows[0]["URLEng"].ToString();
                Name_En = Regex.Replace(Name_En, "[^0-9A-Za-z -]", "").ToLower().Replace(' ', '-');

                if (Convert.ToString(Session["ServiceName"]) != Name_En)
                {
                    Session["ServiceName"] = Name_En;
                    Response.Redirect(CommonFunction.GetLangWiseRedirectLink(1428, 1429) + "/" + Name_En);
                }
                else
                    Session["ServiceName"] = Name_En;
            }
            //          
        }
        else
        {
            Session["ServiceName"] = Request.RawUrl.Substring(Request.RawUrl.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

            //temp code:
            dt1 = FEManager.GetOurServiceByID(CommonFunction.GetLangType(), Session["ServiceName"].ToString());
            if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                if (Session["ServiceName"].ToString() != dt1.Rows[0]["URLAr"].ToString())
                {
                    Response.Redirect(CommonFunction.GetLangWiseRedirectLink(1428, 1429) + "/" + dt1.Rows[0]["URLAr"].ToString());
                }
                Session["ServiceName"] = dt1.Rows[0]["URLAr"].ToString();
            }
        }
        string sessionData1 = Session["ServiceName"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        if (Session["ServiceName"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(CommonFunction.GetLangWiseRedirectLink(1342, 1343));
        }
        else
        {
                          Response.Redirect(CommonFunction.GetLangWiseRedirectLink(1428, 1429) + "/" + Session["ServiceName"].ToString());
        }
    }

    dt = FEManager.GetOurServiceByID(CommonFunction.GetLangType(), Session["ServiceName"].ToString());

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ltContent.Text = dt.Rows[0]["longDesc"].ToString();
        ltHeader.Text = dt.Rows[0]["name"].ToString();
        hdnID.Value = dt.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
        ((DotNetNuke.Framework.CDefault)this.Page).Title = dt.Rows[0]["pageTitle"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: `it gives error as too many redirections which may affect on performace of app.` Please include a screenshot of that error (e.g. so we can see whether it is the browser saying that). What is the original URL? What is the URL that you are redirecting to?

Comment: In Chrome Dev Tools, if you could go to the Network tab, tick `Preserve Log` and then trigger the issue (and include a screenshot of the redirecting URLs) that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you get "too many redirects" it's almost always because you have created an infinite loop of redirects by redirecting to the same page.

Step through the code in a debugger and carefully check the redirect urls.